# regex to find number between 3 spaces after delimited number?

Tags: php, regex

i have a string with numbers and i have a pattern to match the string and getting specific numbers of this string.

```
202-715-1278 2 0.01% 0.30 0.00% $0.00 0.00%
202-715-1278 21 0.01% 0.30 0.00% $0.00 0.00%
202-715-1278 210 0.01% 0.30 0.00% $0.00 0.00%
```

pattern

```
\b[0-9]{3}\s*[-]\s*[0-9]{3}\s*[-]\s*[0-9]{4}|(?<!\$)\b[-+]?\d+\.\d+\b(?!%)|(\$\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\b
```

this pattern return the phone number the first float number which is 0.30 and the price .
what i need is to return the number between the 2 space after the phone number which is 2 , 21 or 210 in this example .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the regex you currently have a bit weird, since it seems that the values you're looking for can be anywhere in the string. Well, following the way the regex was written, you might use:

```
\b[0-9]{3}\s*[-]\s*[0-9]{3}\s*[-]\s*[0-9]{4}|(?<!\$)\b[-+]?\d+\.\d+\b(?!%)|(\$\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\b|\b(?<!\$)(\d+)(?!%|\.)\b
```

I added the bit: `|\b(?<!\$)(\d+)(?!%|\.)\b` by the way. A demo can be found [here](http://www.regex101.com/r/gI3qR2).

Answer (score 0):

I would not use a regex for that. Use `explode()` instead:

```
// split the lines
$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $string);

foreach($lines as $line) {
    // split line by spaces
    $record = explode(' ', $line);
    // now you can access every column in the record
    var_dump($record);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't `explode("\n", str_replace("\r", '', $string))` be better, as the data might come from a source that doesn't run the same operative system? If the data comes from a Linux source, `PHP_EOL` would most likely be `\n` (from the source), but the server running the PHP might believe that `PHP_EOL` is `\r\n` and hence not explode anything at all.

Comment: @h2ooooooo Yes, the line delimiter will need special attention if the file doesn't come from a linux box and php runs on linux. `PHP_EOL` is just an example and I like it most in my answers. because if I just write `\r\n` it will not work on UNIX if I type `\n` it will not work on Windows. You cannot do it right without knowing more about the application. I think `PHP_EOL` is at least expressive

Answer (score 0):

if you're only after the numbers following the phone number and space, you could cut down the expression to

```
\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}\s(\d+)
```

Comment: yes but i need to return it as individual number just like other filters to have an element into the the match array

Answer (score 0):

Haven testes it but this should do the work:

```
foreach($lines as $line){
    $results=array();
    preg_match('%(\d+-\d+-\d+).*( \d+\.\d+ ).*(\$\d+\.\d+).*%', $line, $results);
    $phone=$results[1];
    $float=$results[2];
    $price=$results[3];
}
```

Edit: Short test reveals that is't working http://regexr.com?35f81 :)

Answer (score 0):

Agree with other reply, regexp seems useless (explode probably faster), but if you need it why not use something simple like:

```
/([0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+) ([0-9]+) ([0-9.]+%) ([0-9.]+) ([0-9.]+%) \$([0-9.]+) ([0-9.]+%)/
```

You will have all fields in \1 \2 \3 etc..

http://www.regex101.com/r/lX1aW2